# An android Text Editor

Tags: android, text, editor, text-editor

I want to create a text editor for Android.

Can anyone give me an example or sample from where I can start?

Comment: Question is far to broad for our scope. My suggestion is for you to look for a blog or forum to ask this question. This site is for more specific and focused questions.

Comment: If you download the Android samples for any platform via the Android SDK Manager, there is a complete Notepad project in the legacy folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an example?  Look here https://github.com/asif0047/textEditor

A can give you a little bit Tipps for the Way.

You need two Activties. Once for the File Lists that you are edit. From here you can share the Data or Copy the file.

The other one for the Text Editor. It represent all the thinks what you are want, so rename, paste, save, color chose.

Hope that suggestion help you

Comment: One could also create only one activity but two fraents for this. This way you can also optimize your UI for tablets.